# create schema during build for hibernate-4 using annotated classes

Tags: hibernate, maven, schema

I'm trying to upgrade to Hibernate 4.1.3 (from 3.6.9). The model is annotation based (that is, persistent classes are defined with @Entity and @Column annotations)

The maven build uses hibernate3-maven-plugin to create the sql script for the schema, but the plugin doesn't work with 4.1.3. I thought of using SchemaExportTask vi antrun, however my understanding is that I need to explicitly configure the classes to analyse and I don't know how to get them in maven. So how do I provide the task with the classes?

Any other help to create the schema would be great.

Comment: Which version of the hibernate3-maven-plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.2. I tried using 3.0 but couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Juplo has created [Maven plugin for Hibernate 4](http://juplo.de/hibernate4-maven-plugin/index.html). The plugin automatically scans your project for annotated classes and supports schema export including Envers. Working example is below. Check [official plugin configuration documentation](http://juplo.de/hibernate4-maven-plugin/export-mojo.html) to get more information on used options.

The plugin generates `schema.sql` file in the Maven `/target` directory on `test` goal.
Or you can manually run `hibernate4:export` goal to update the file.

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.juplo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>export</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <envers>true</envers>
                    <format>true</format>
                    <delimiter>;</delimiter>
                    <force>true</force>
                    <type>CREATE</type>
                    <target>SCRIPT</target>
                    <hibernateDialect>org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</hibernateDialect>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```